# Append Data in Session

Tags: asp.net, session

I need a help to append data in session variable.

What is am doing is as follows..

```
Session["subContractors"]  = CallNodesSelector(objSubContractorOptions, Convert.ToInt16(item));
```

I have popup and and on some operations on popup my CallNodeSelector method returs object and stores it into session variable. but next time again when i open pop up and do some operation it is adding fresh data returned by method and my old data in session is getting lost. In short session is getting overwritten every time method returns its data.

Can anyone help me to append data in session.
Something like this....

```
Session["subContractors"]  += CallNodesSelector(objSubContractorOptions, Convert.ToInt16(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `CallNodesSelector(objSubContractorOptions, Convert.ToInt16(item))` returns an int, why don't you try this?

```
Session["subContractors"] = (int)(Session["subContractors"] ?? 0) + CallNodesSelector(objSubContractorOptions, Convert.ToInt16(item));
```